# What function(s) can satisfy this condition?

Tags: real-analysis

An infinitely differentiable function that is not represented by a convergent power series in any open interval containing the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ for $x \ne 0$, $0$ for $x = 0$. Compute the derivatives at $0$, that will tell you why the function is not the sum of a convergent power series near $0$. The intuition is that $f(x)$ decreases to zero much faster than any power of $x$, which proves both infinite differentiability and the fact that it's not the sum of a power series.